# Joining table created_at and updated_at values not being set

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models, Product and Attribute. There is a 'product_attributes' joining table between 'products' and 'attributes'. The relationship is defined in both models using belongsToMany(), and the key of the table is a compound one of product_id and attribute_id.

I can successfully retrieve and store records in the joining table - so, as such everything is functioning as expected, with the exception that the created_at and updated_at in product_attributes is not being set.

Is the above by design, and is there anything I can do to rectify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `belongsToMany` function with the `timestamps` declaration like this:

```
$this->belongsToMany(<entity>)->withTimestamps();
```